# Better way to convert IEnumerable<T> to user type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a custom collection type, defined as such:

```
public abstract class RigCollectionBase<T> : Collection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, IBindingList, ICancelAddNew where T : BusinessObjectBase, new()
```

Note: this is the base class, there are 20 or so child classes that are implemented like so:

```
public class MyCollection : RigCollectionBase<MyObject>
```

We use a lot of Linq in our code, and as you probably know, Linq functions return `IEnumerable<T>`.  What I'm looking for, is an easy and simple way to go back to `MyCollection` from `IEumberable<MyObject>`.  Casting is not allowed, I get the exception "Cannot cast from ..."

Here is the answer I came up with, and it *does* work, but it seems kind of clunky and...overcomplicated.  Maybe its not, but I figured I would get this out there to see if there's a better way.

```
public static class Extension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Turn your IEnumerable into a RigCollection
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The Collection type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="U">The Type of the object in the collection</typeparam>
    /// <param name="col"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T MakeRigCollection<T, U> (this IEnumerable<U> col) where T : RigCollectionBase<U>, new() where U : BusinessObjectBase, new()
    {
        T retCol = new T();

        foreach (U myObj in col)
            retCol.Add(myObj);

        return retCol;
    }
}
```

What I'm really looking for, I guess, is this.  Is there a way to implement the base class so that I can use a simple cast to go from IEnumerable into MyCollection...

```
var LinqResult = oldCol.Where(a=> someCondition);
MyCollection newCol = (MyCollection)LinqResult;
```

No, the above code doesn't work, and I'm actually not 100% certain why that is...but it doesn't.  It just feels like there is some very obvious step that I'm not seeing....

Comment: Is there a reason you need your own form of collection? Also, your MakeRigCollection method could be turned into an iterator if you use the yield keywords instead that way you'd get the "streaming" behaviour linq is so good at preserved.

Comment: I think I'd prefer that extension method as a constructor on RigCollectionBase

Comment: You need to clear about when you are iterating over an enumerable, you have decomposed the source data from its original form into a pipeline. If you want to take that pipeline and re-compose the original composite data, you could pass the ienumerable<t> to your class's constructor, assuming you have one that populates its data from an ienumerable<t> of its type, like the BCL's data structures do.

Comment: I can't really put this in as a constructor at the base level, because the class is declared abstract.  I could change that I suppose, but I will never have any reason in the code itself to create individual instances of the base collection.  That's why I built this as an extension in the first place, so that I would be able to generate `MyCollection` objects from it, but still have the code in the base class.

Comment: @Clint business coding standards mostly.  I would have been happier dealing with everything as List<MyObject> and then custom defining the objects only.  But the standard for the project, long long ago and way over my head, was to create the custom collections.  I had to fight long and hard to get the base class implemented, we didn't even have that at first!!

Comment: @Nevyn I hear you, I used to work for a company that had some pretty outrageous coding standards, it always sucks when you can't have the best solution because of higher up decisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `MakeRigCollection` is basically the right way to do it. Here is a variant that is slightly more verbose to use but much simpler to implement:

```
TCollection MakeRigCollectionSimple<TCollection, TItem>(
    this IEnumerable<TItem> items, TCollection collection)
    where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>
{
        foreach (var myObj in items)
            collection.Add(myObj);
        return collection;
}
```

I hope I got it right. You use it like this:

```
MakeRigCollectionSimple(items, new MyCollection());
```

or

```
items.MakeRigCollectionSimple(new MyCollection());
```

Now you have the 2nd argument to fill out, but in exchange we were able to get rid of all the crazy generics stuff. Just simple generics left. And type inference kicks in fully. Also, this will work for *all* collection types, not just your RigCollections.

Comment: what purpose does the TCollection parameter have?  either you forgot something in the implementation or its purpose is rather non-obvious.

Comment: I figured it out `retCol` is actually the `collection` parameter.  This is basically the same function, but calling it is simpler.  make it as an extension and the actual function call is `whateverEnumerator.MakeRigCollection(new MyCollection());`.  I chose it as the answer due to the added simplicity.  Good call :-)

Comment: Your edit got rejected by someone else. I just fixed everything up.

Answer (score 2):

While your collection does implement `IEnumerable<T>`, you can't cast a simple `IEnumerable<T>` to your specific collection because of how inheritance works.

That's why there are built-in LINQ extension methods such as `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`, that does exactly what you wrote.

The only difference is that `List<T>` provides a public constructor that takes `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter.

Comment: Can I cast from `List<T>` to my object type if I implement `IList<T>` on the base class?  No idea why i would do that since I extend `Collection<T>` though...seems kinda silly...

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to `MyCollection` that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, and do:

```
var newCol = new MyCollection(oldCol.Where(a=> someCondition));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast, because the LINQ methods don't change your original collection. They return new ones. The new ones aren't instances of your collection but of LINQ-specific collections, depending on which method you used. The reason for this is the deferred nature of the LINQ methods.

You have several possibilities:

1. You could create an explicit or implicit cast operator in your class but you would need to implement it in every one of your child classes.
2. You can create a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and directly initialize your collection from it - similar to the constructor on `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit complicated, but in general you can imagine, that LINQ enumerates through your collection (no matter of the type, it is just important, that it can be converted into [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx)) and adds all matching object references to a new list. It depends on the [`IQueryProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryprovider.aspx) which container object is used to collect the query results. So the most obvious option is to [create an custom `IQueryProvider`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx). Everybody who tried this, knows how much pain this can be...

However `IQueryProvider` typically returns an [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which leads to two options:

1. Use LINQ's [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261.aspx) extension method, to create an [`System.Collections.Generic.List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx) and continue using simple lists as containers, or
2. Add an constructor, accepting an `IEnumerable`.

Both ways are much more similar, than you might think, because `ToList` is implemented somehow like this:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return new List<T>(enumerable);
}
```

So it simply delegates all the hard work to the [respective constructor of `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fkbw11z0.aspx).

Most collections are supporting construction by `IEnumerable` parameters. I don't actually know why [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) doesn't support `IEnumerable`, but [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx). However this gives you the possibility to implement your collection base class with two additional constructors to simplify your queries' results:

```
MyRigCollectionBase(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    : this (enumerable.ToList())
{
    // Delegates to constructor below
}

MyRigCollectionBase(IList<T> list)
    : base (list)
{
    // Delegates to constructor of Collection<T>.
}
```

This does not really solve your overload, but it gives you the chance to build up custom collections from queries:

```
var coll = new MyCollection(oldColl.Where(x => x.AddToList));
```

And it give's clients the possibility to use different ways to manage their query results.

Also this enables you to provide custom extensions: <sup>1</sup>

```
public class MyCollection : MyRigCollectionBase<MyObject>
{
    public static ToMyCollection(this IEnumerable<MyObject> enumerable)
    {
        return new MyCollection(enumerable);   // Calls our previously declared constructor.
    }
}
```

Now you can query like this:

```
var coll = oldColl.Where(x => x.AddToList).ToMyCollection();
```

Each specialization of your collection could define it's own extension within the scope of it's declaration. Each query that returns an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` would be able to convert it's result into `MyCollection`.

<sup>1</sup>
<sup><sub>I am not 100% sure if `this IEnumerable<MyObject>` works as an parameter, and the extension can get called for an query returning `IEnumerable<MyObject>`. Some confirmation would be nice!</sub></sup>

Comment: Good answer, but the issue is that I have the base class declared as abstract, which means no constructors except in the children, which somewhat defeats the point of having a single point of implementation for this.  Well explained and well reasoned though.

Comment: You can have constructors in abstract base classes ;)

Comment: I stand corrected, I had attemtped the implementation wrong.  Have to use `RigCollectionBase` rather than `RigCollectionBase<T>` when declaring the constructor...

Comment: However, after implementing the two constructors I get a whole list of errors about how the base type constrcutors are not implemented. Literally every single custom collection class....I dont want to have to change every single custom collection class I already have, that's part of the goal, even if the actual implementation i need is rediculously simple

Comment: You do not have to redefine those constructors. You just need to call them! You can do this by using the keyword `base` behind the constructor... I did this once in the answer, too ;) If you do not want to call those constructors with `IEnumerable` or `IList`, you can also declare an empty constructor at the base class and call it using `: base()` - this is exactly there for "doing things once": Namely initializing the base members only on one place in the code ;)

Comment: The error I get is "Class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments".  When I create a default constructor for the class rather than letting it auto-implement, it not only tells me its a redundant constructor, but the error does not go away, same error by the way.  The advice under the error according to the refactor code is "Base Type constructors are not implemented".  When I solve the issue, it implements the two constructors from the base class in the child class.  Hence, I have to define these constructors in every one of the child classes to compile the code.  Thus, my issue.

Comment: Ok, finally figured out why that isn't working.  You _have_ to declare the default constructor as well, in the base class, or nothing will ever compile.  We are however left with a different issue.  The child class does not have access to the new constructor, even though its declared as public.  `new MyChildCollection(enumerable)` does not compile, MyChildCollection does not contain a constructor with 1 argument.  Leading back to my original point, without echoing this constructor into every child collection, its essentially un-usable.

Comment: Yes, of course you have to define an constructor that takes an `IEnumerable` or `IList` in your specialized classes - I haven't told anything different. This makes perfect sense, since you want to keep control over the initialization of your specialized class (maybe you want collections that are not able to be initialized using `IEnumerable`). This only give's you the possibility to write initialization code once and call it over the whole inheritance hierarchy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely cannot just cast `IEnumerable<T>` to your custom type, since compiler will never know how to do this conversion. Unless you tell it how using [conversion operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

Comment: That's not strictly true. If the `IEnumerable<T>` object happens to already be an instance of the custom type, the casting will be safe.

Comment: You mean in this case at least it won't fail at runtime, right? Anyway, this is not something I would call 'safe')

Comment: I like the link to implicit and explicit constructors...didn't know how to do that before.  Wont give me the answer im looking for since I need something implementable at the base level though, i dont want to have to redefine the constructor in every child class I have/will create.

Comment: Long time since I last played with this.  Something interesting to know though...You cannot define an explicit operator for an interface.  I could define one for List, Array, or anything else that implements IEnumerable, but not IEnumerable by itself.  Its a compiler error and wont let me.  The exact message is: `user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed`